# How to add swap to ECS containers?

Tags: linux, memory, amazon-web-services

My EC2 instance is running out of memory, and I thought adding swap could help

I'm not sure EC2 ran out of memory or container did, following is screenshot of EC2 offered by AWS get-instance-screenshot

[image: ScreenShot of instance]

Doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-swap.html says we can add swap.. So I added the following to task definition and deployed it

```
        "linuxParameters": {
            "capabilities": null,
            "sharedMemorySize": null,
            "tmpfs": null,
            "devices": null,
            "maxSwap": 2048,
            "swappiness": 60,
            "initProcessEnabled": null
        },

        "memory": null,
        "memoryReservation": 512,
```

I log in to the ec2 host and see top, there's no `Swap` assigned (0 total, 0 free) both in host and container..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the documentation page you link to there's this statement:

> **Note**
>
> The Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs do not have swap enabled by default. You
>   must enable swap on the instance to use this feature. For more
>   information, see Instance Store Swap Volumes in the Amazon EC2 User
>   Guide for Linux Instances or How do I allocate memory to work as swap
>   space in an Amazon EC2 instance by using a swap file?.

Have you followed the instructions in the links provided there to configure swap on your instance (not just in the task definition):

Please also note the best practice recommendation to only use ephemeral instance storage for swap space (as opposed to EBS volumes).

- [Instance Store Swap Volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-store-swap-volumes.html)
- [How do I allocate memory to work as swap space in an Amazon EC2 instance by using a swap file](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-memory-swap-file/)